# ValueError when converting String to datetime

Tags: python

I have a dataframe as follows, and I am trying to reduce the dataframe to only contain rows for which the Date is greater than a variable `curve_enddate`. The `df['Date']` is in `datetime` and hence I'm trying to convert `curve_enddate[i][0]` which gives a string of the form `2015-06-24` to `datetime` but am getting the error `ValueError: time data '2015-06-24' does not match format '%Y-%b-%d'`.

```
              Date      Maturity      Yield_pct Currency
0       2015-06-24          0.25             na      CAD
1       2015-06-25          0.25   0.0948511020      CAD
```

The line where I get the Error:

```
df = df[df['Date'] > time.strptime(curve_enddate[i][0], '%Y-%b-%d')]
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare a *time.struct_time tuple*  which is what `time.strptime` returns to a `Timestamp` so you also need to change that as well as using  `'%Y-%m-%d'` using `m` which is the month *as a decimal number*. You can use `pd.to_datetime` to create the object to compare:

```
df = df[df['Date'] > pd.to_datetime(curve_enddate[i][0], '%Y-%m-%d')]
```

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham You were right about the`time.struct_time tuple` issue. However, I now get the error `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'`. Would you know why this is?

Comment: Yes, you did not convert your `Date` column to a datetime. Did you use read_csv to create the df?

Comment: Try `df[df["Date"].apply(pd.to_datetime) > pd.to_datetime(curve_enddate[i][0], '%Y-%m-%d')]]`, if you plan on using the dates a lot, I would set them permanently once. If you are using read_csv use `converters={"Date":pd.to_datetime}` to cast to datetime

Answer (score 4):

You are using wrong date format, `%b` is for the named months (abbreviations like `Jan` or `Feb` , etc), use `%m` for the numbered months.

Code -

```
df = df[df['Date'] > time.strptime(curve_enddate[i][0], '%Y-%m-%d')]
```